# Deploying an artifact, its sources and javadoc using maven's deploy:deploy-file plugin

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm stumped trying to deploy an artifact, its sources and its javadoc to our maven repository (Nexus). The sources and javadoc parameters seems to be ignored, and only the main jar specified in -Dfile is actually uploaded.

Does anyone know what's wrong? Here's my command (I'm trying to put Whack into our local repository)

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=whack-1.0.0.jar \ 
                       -Dsources=whack-1.0.0-sources.jar \
                       -Djavadoc=whack-1.0.0-javadoc.jar \
                       -DgroupId=org.igniterealtime \                     
                       -DartifactId=whack \
                       -Dversion=1.0.0 \
                       -Dpackaging=jar \
                       -Durl=https://myhost.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/
```

Comment: By the way, I am aware that I can use the Nexus web interface to upload an artifact and everything that goes with it. I just would like to do it from the command line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First check if you are using plugin version 2.7. According [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#sources) the option `sources` and `javadoc` are available from this version on.

If you using the correct version and it still doesn't work you can deploy the artifacts using old way - in multiple command.

To deploy source jar use:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=whack-1.0.0-sources.jar \
                       -Dclassifier=sources
                       -DgroupId=org.igniterealtime \                     
                       -DartifactId=whack \
                       -Dversion=1.0.0 \
                       -Dpackaging=jar \
                       -Durl=https://myhost.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/
```

and javadoc jar:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=whack-1.0.0-javadoc.jar \
                       -Dclassifier=javadoc
                       -DgroupId=org.igniterealtime \                     
                       -DartifactId=whack \
                       -Dversion=1.0.0 \
                       -Dpackaging=jar \
                       -Durl=https://myhost.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/
```

Comment: Ok, so classifier is what I was missing.. And yeap, I'm using version 2.5 of the plugin.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to additionally specify the -DrepositoryId